# WP7 : Bind a MenuItem inside a datatemplate of a ContextMenu to a List<T>

Tags: windows-phone-7, binding, contextmenu, datatemplate

I'm quite new in Xaml developpement (WPF,Sliverlight,WP7).

Here is my problem:

I've got a customized button, when I click on it (long click or hold), I'd like to open a specific contextMenu related to a List. It means, the menuItem header have a different text due to the button we clicked.

Here is a sample code:
My list

```
public class ListTest
{
    private List<string> testList;

    public List<string> TestList
    {
        get { return testList; }
        set { testList = value; }
    }


    public ListTest()
    {
        testList = new List<string>();
        testList.Add("1st Header");
        testList.Add("2nd Header");
        testList.Add("3rd Header");
        testList.Add("4th Header");
    }
}
```

my Mainpage WP7

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ListTest tst = new ListTest();
        this.DataContext = tst.TestList;
    }
```

My XAML code

```
 <my:OwnButton IconSource="Image/beer.png" DrinkText="Beer" x:Name="btnBeer1">
                    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                        <toolkit:ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                            <toolkit:ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate >
                                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="{Binding}" /> 
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </toolkit:ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>

                        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                </my:OwnButton>
```

Acutally, I tought my contextmenu menuitem will fill automaticily by the List as this is list is set as DataContext of the MainPage. When I run my application, my contextmenu is empty. Help?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the data template to this:

```
<DataTemplate >
    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="{Binding TestList}" /> 
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Not sure that will work as he's already assigning the DataContext to the TestList property